# Deleted folder on arch with "rm -rf" does not free space

Tags: arch-linux, disk-usage, rm

I deleted a folder containing some rust code I duplicated for testing some time ago - it took up some 10gb worth of space. I noticed this while trying to clear up space and deleted the folder with `rm -rf folder`.

Now the problem is that `df` doesn't reflect this 10gb freed space, but `du` does. How do I fix this?

As requested, I have added the output from `df` and `du` below:

```
$ df -H /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4       129G  113G   15G  89% /
```

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1 /
96M     /boot
28G     /var
0       /dev
1.7M    /run
14M     /etc
8.0K    /tmp
0       /sys
0       /proc
13G     /usr
65G     /home
0       /mnt
243M    /opt
135M    /root
0       /srv
105G    /
```

I also use btrfs.

Comment: We can't see the output from `df` on your machine, nor do we know what type of filesystem you're using, so we can't say much about this.

Comment: I have added more information, can I get any pointers?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing, at least, whether the same inodes are referenced by other filenames, whether the files in question are present in snapshots, etc.

Comment: Mind you that du, at least when run as you did, includes also space used on external filesystems mounted on the system, heck, it could even show an overall "disk" usage larger than the disk itself... Which in a related fashion leads to the question: were your files actually saved on the root partition? I see you're checking '/' with df, and that '/' is on sda4, so there are at least other 3 partitions on that drive (and counting swap + efi + '/' would add up just to 3). Could it be that you're mounting '/home' on a different partition? And that the files you mention were saved under '/home'?

Comment: `/dev/sda4` is the root partition, and `/home` is mounted there. The folder I deleted was under `/home/user/code/deleted_folder`. Also I checked for snapshots using `btrfs subvolume list /` it gave two entries which I deleted.